# General proof tactic for showing a.s. limit equalities?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits, stochastic-processes, random-variables

I am interested in problems of the form:

Show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty} X_n=C \text{ a.s.} $$
where $C$ is some known constant.

I would like to know if there are any "classic" ways of dealing with such problems.

One idea that I had was showing that $\limsup_{n\to \infty} X_n\leq C$ a.s. and $\liminf_{n\to \infty} X_n\geq C$ a.s. but I was hoping for some more ideas one could try when faced with such a problem.

Comment: One approach would be to use the Borel-Cantelli lemmas, (or some other kind of 0-1 law) to show that events like $\{|X_n - C| > \epsilon \text { i.o.}\}$ have probability zero. (it often helps to replace $\epsilon$ with some sequence $\langle \epsilon_n\rangle_{n \in \mathbb N}$ converging to $0$) Then $\{|X_n - C| \le \epsilon \text { e.v.}\}$ will have probability $1$. Taking a union over rational $\epsilon > 0$ we then obtain $\{\forall \epsilon > 0 : |X_n - C| \le \epsilon \text { e.v.}\}$ occurs with probability $1$. This is precisely almost-sure convergence of $X$

Comment: I think I already saw and/or used this before! Thank you very much for the comment! Just one question, what is e.v. short for? I am assuming it should mean eventually, but the full stop is throwing me off...

Comment: Eventually, yes.

Comment: Another option is to show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[|X_n-C|^p] < \infty$ for some $p \ge 1$.  This would show $(X_n) \rightarrow C$ a.s. by the monotone convergence theorem.  One can alternatively show $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{E}[|X_n-C|^p]^{1/p} < \infty$ and use the same proof after applying Minkoski's inequality to $\mathbb{E}[|\sum_{n=1}^\infty (X_n-C)|^p]^{1/p}$.

Comment: Strong law of large numbers can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you @user6247850, that's a good idea as well!

Comment: As for the suggestion by @fes, I also wanted to use this, but this works with iid RVs, and we do not always have that. But still thank you for pointing that out!